# Importing and working with word2vec GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz into R

Tags: r, word2vec

I am big fan of word2vec algorithm. I had obtained vectors binary file made by google research team and I would like to make some analysis on that (which I had previously made on much smaller datasets than google had made).

I am not able to import the file GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz into the R.

I had extracted that, and using rword2vec (found on github) transformed from bin to txt file.
There is a kind of searching function inside the package, but it is sooo slooow.

That is why I am now attempting to import the file inside R and transform it to dataframe , if possible, with structure:

```
name | vec1 | ... | vec300
```

I had tried built in readBin (could not obtain names), also readLines with txt (did not finish) or readr package and read_lines (made only 12Mb big vector)

could you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way.

Using package [rword2vec](http://www.rpubs.com/mukul13/rword2vec), it is possible to use either function bin_to_txt or framework provided in the package. For more information see the vignette provided.

```
library(rword2vec)
dist=distance(file_name = "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin",search_word = "king",num = 10)
dist
```

> ```
>            word              dist
> 1         kings 0.713804960250854
> 2         queen 0.651095926761627
> 3       monarch 0.641319692134857
> 4  crown_prince 0.620422065258026
> 5        prince 0.615999639034271
> 6        sultan 0.586482524871826
> 7         ruler 0.579756796360016
> 8       princes 0.564655303955078
> 9  Prince_Paras 0.543294668197632
> 10       throne 0.542210519313812
> ```